# How do i change a grid in windows application automatically after change its table on DB?

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, windows

I have a scenario that its will doing like a messenger !

Imagine i  have a grid-view in Windows app and this Grid-View show all records on a table in my database . i need when something changed a record on database (insert - Update - Delete) automatically grid view in my windows app changed and updated with new records According to Data Base Table !

I know one of solution is used background worker in behind and use interval checking in Database table (for example for each 1 second) but it used resource of system so much. i want something that push records from database to windows app !! is There any solution for this propose ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SignalR framework that push the data from the server to your application, it's usually used by ASP.NET but it can be used in desktop apps as well.

check this code for how to implement it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

Note: You will have to run a web server with the application

Comment: thanks it sounds good . i will research on it and will write result in here ...

Answer (score 0):

If by

> grid-view in Windows app

you are using Windows Forms and you have a `DataGridView`, you can add a control of type `BindingSource` then bind the `DataSource` property of the grid to the database query that returns the data you want to display.